# Midje, provided not working as I expect

Tags: clojure, midje

I have written the following Midje test:

```
(fact (followers-minus-friends ...name...) => ["Dude"]
      (provided (idset show-followers ...name...) => #{1 2 3}
                (idset show-friends ...name...) => #{1 2}
                (userinfos #{3}) => [{:screen_name "Dude"}]))
```

to test the following function (in a different namespace):

```
(defn followers-minus-friends [screenname]
  (let [difference-ids (difference (idset show-followers screenname)
                                   (idset show-friends screenname))
        userinfos (userinfos difference-ids)]
    (map :screen_name userinfos)))
```

The test may seem pretty useless, but I'm just trying to get accustomed to Midje. Somehow, the function idset just gets executed, which I wanted to prevent by providing a return value in the provided-clause. What could be an explanation for this?

**EDIT**: I have uploaded the project to Github here, in case you want to try to reproduce the above situation: https://github.com/Borkdude/twitter-utils

Comment: Without knowing the details of the function tested i have tried to reproduce the case with https://gist.github.com/1359355 and i think the function is not executed

Comment: @jneira: added some more details.

Comment: @jneira: project is now up at github: https://github.com/Borkdude/twitter-utils

Comment: I'm just getting caught up to Clojure and Midje. Would you mind explaining what the "...name..." symbol is and how it's used in this context? Thanks!

Comment: I answered my own question! https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Metaconstants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function `idset` is private in your source namespace. In the test file, you intern it in the test namespace. You now have two *different* vars that point to the same function:

```
 #'twitter-utils.core/idset
 #'twitter-utils.test.core/idset
```

In the `provided`, you are overriding the second var to point to a prerequisite function. However, the function `followers-minus-friends` still refers to the first var. That is not overridden, so you get the original function.

A common idiom for routing around `private` declarations is to use the full var name, as above. So you'd expect this to work:

```
(fact (followers-minus-friends ...name...) => ["Dude"]
      (provided (#'twitter-utils.core/idset show-followers ...name...) => #{1 2 3}
                (#'twitter-utils.core/idset show-friends ...name...) => #{1 2}
                (userinfos #{3}) => [{:screen_name "Dude"}]))
```

It doesn't, though. I consider that a bug in Midje. At least, I can't offhand see what harm supporting that would do. I'll file a ticket.

As it stands, you need to make `idset` public.